# Magento 2 products not showing up - tried everything

Tags: php, magento

I have 1000 products, they all show up in the admin panel under catalog. They are all enabled, have inventory over 0, they are all visible in catalog, search... I am running single store mode so I don't have a store to assign them to.

I have ran re-index a few times. I have deployed static content several times. I have cleared cache manually (CLI) and thru admin panel. I have deleted everything in var/cache, var/di etc... and ran update/compile. I have set chmod to 777 on those folders.

What else can I try?

There are no errors in the javascript console. The only error I see is in Admin when I refresh a product page I get an error that "Attention: Something went wrong."

The products were imported from X-Cart using the Lit extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try running compilation command : php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Also please check the logs in var/log folder exception.log & system.log files

If nothing fruitful then please try disabling the extensions one by one & running php bin/magento setup:upgrade command after disabling extension/s, and yes please also check the permissions of files & folders.....if you are working on live server it should be 644 for files & 755 for folders. If you are working in local pc then it should be 777 for all files & folders.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run: /bin/php /bin/magento indexer:reset

After that login to your virtual product and check Stock Status.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

In admin click to edit product and then change your store view from "All store views" to "Default Store View" and then check stock , status, categories etc. And then save the product. And then execute reindex command and flush cache.php

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex.
php bin/magento cache:flush.
```

Hope It helps you!!!